# Second video card not working

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, nvidia

I have a system running fine with an Nvidia GTX 1650, I decided to add a second video card I had lying around to connect extra monitors and having them not share the primary GPU.
Windows 11 seems to detect the second device fine in the
device manager

[image: 1]

but it is not shown in the Nvidia Control Panel:

[image: 2]

nor in Windows 11 display settings:

[image: 3]

and the attached monitor is blank.
I tried running the software called GPU-Z and it detects both cards just fine

[image: 4]

I updated my drivers, what else can I do?

EDIT: I realize that if I tell the 960 to use an older version of the drivers it works, but it also overwrites the 1650 drivers.
It looks like you can only have one particular instance of NVIDIA drivers running at once, and all devices are going to use the last you installed

Comment: Try [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/1322637/how-can-i-get-two-nvidia-gpus-of-different-generations-kepler-pascal-to-run).